# Is there a way to remove songs in a playlist from an iOS device?

Tags: ios, icloud, itunes-match, playlist

There are situations where (for example to free up storage) on an iOS device with iTunes Match enabled, it would be nice to be able to remove songs on the device, based on certain attributes. For example, it would be convenient to be able to remove all songs one has given low ratings. Match makes the first part of this easy: it is a simple matter to set up a smart playlist that is synced through iCloud to the iOS device; but it appears that (while it is possible to download missing songs from within a playlist) it is not possible to remove them. Is this in fact the case?

Is there no way to remove songs from a device from within a playlist?

Comment: Note: I understand that one can delete songs from a (non-smart) playlist, but this question is about removing the file from the device (leaving the list unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you are trying to remove one file from the device.

I do not believe this is possible to remove individual songs that have been cached over iTunes Match on your iOS device (at this stage). Your alternative is to turn off Match from `Settings -> Music -> iTunes Match` to clear off all cached items and free up space

Comment: No, it _is_ possible to delete individual songs from an iOS device. That's not my question. The question is whether it was possible to delete when they are displayed as part of a playlist on the device.